# calculate weight of stock in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, like shown below.

```
company    shares     price
abc        10         5
def        2          30
xyz        8          4
```

I want to calculate the weight of each company in a new column.

So currently I do the following,

```
 df['value'] = df.shares * df.price
 df['weight'] = df['value'] / df['value'].sum()
 df.drop('value', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Whilst the above works fine. I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing this. I often seen the apply function being used, is this a good time to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` solutions here are slowier/worse, because loops under the hood. Your solution is better, because vectorized.

You can simplify solution for assign to `Series`, not new column, so not encessary remove it in last step:

```
s = df.shares * df.price
df['weight'] = s / s.sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance, the method you chose will suffice. It is more concise and will execute code faster. These are not the instances where the `apply()` function is used, it's when every single value needs to be applied to a function and when you need to divide data based upon specific conditions that you used `apply`.
Using it here will only make it more convoluted in this case.